# Why large queueing delays are experienced as a packet arrival rate nears the link's capacity?

Tags: tcp, transport-protocol, congestion

From the book "Computer Networks A top Down Approach":

[image: Congestion Scenario]

[image: Delay as a function of host sending rate]

It says if hosts A and B both are sending at rate R/2 and router's outgoing link has a capacity of R. There will be delays experienced by the packets from both A and B in queue at the router. I have two questions:

1. Why there isn't a queue in the first place at the switch's outgoing link connecting Hosts A and B to the router? (May the outgoing link of switch is much larger than A and B sending rate.)
2. If outgoing link of router is of capacity R and incoming traffic rate from each host is R/2, then there shouldn't be any queue and subsequently no delay experienced by the packets from both hosts.

Comment: Is the que experienced at the router buffers due to processing (link layer error recovery, router table lookup etc.) of each packet

Comment: No, that was asked by me and the scenario over there is different i suppose

Comment: How do you understand that it's different?  It seems the same to me.

Comment: Overe there, the traffic intensity is random in a sense that the packet arrival rate sometimes exceeds the transmission capacity and sometimes lesser than the transmission capacity. So the traffic intensity La/R is close to 1 on an average.
Over here Host A and B and constantly sending at rate R/2 each.

Comment: There isn't really much difference. The turning point comes when the egress rate cannot be utilized 100% due to overhead and the ingress rate (in average) is too high - even slightly. A growing queue means growing delay and a bloated queue means large delay. That delay curve is only true when the ingress rate fluctuates significantly, causing substantial jitter in packet delay. In practice, congestion handling works against this effect and you don't really see that.

Comment: "when the egress rate cannot be utilized 100% due to overhead"
what is meant by that?

Comment: @AJHUNTER That is pretty well laid out in the linked answer.

Comment: @Zac67
Does overhead mean processing delay inside a router?

Comment: Yes, processing overhead (there's also protocol overhead, encoding overhead, ...).

Comment: There could be different reasons for this. Mostly - based on architecture, but also could be due to what’s explained within the provided link (aka microbursts). Every port on every ethernet device has a buffer. How this buffer is managed is very dependent on platform and hardware. Some platforms have this as shared resource which leads to one interface exceeding what other links are able to consume (albeit not being congested). And to your question - queues/buffers are needed for many reasons, one of which is speed mismatch (e.g server connected at 40G, and clients at 1, 10, etc)

Comment: My bad: I did not clearly saw the y axis annotation which is "DELAY" and not only "Queuing Delay".